# Script to Generate Self signed SSL certificate

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

Question is around how to quickly generate a self signed certificate that you can use with Agg Cat services OR with other intuit services.

Is there a simple script.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple script I created for this :

```
#!/bin/bash
if (( $# != 2 ))
then
    echo "Usage: aliasname password"
    exit 1
fi

keytool -genkey -keystore ./$1.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12 -storepass $2 -alias $1 -keyalg "RSA" -keysize 2048 -validity 9000
openssl pkcs12 -in $1.p12
keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore ./$1.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass $2 -destkeystore ./$1.jks -deststoretype JKS -deststorepass $2
```

This will create an SSL certificate and print the private key and public cert.

You use the pub cert during app creation

Use the private key in the sample app of API Explorer.